# Merge request: city-state with civilization-5

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-merging

We currently have six questions tagged with [city-state](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city-state)

These questions are all pertaining to [civilization-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5). I propose we either merge the two tags, or delete the [city-state](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city-state) tag altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our local shark moderator has solved this problem. What an awesome guy.